# Trying to understand .NET regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've been doing a lot of reading on .NET regular expressions and I have developed a regular expression, that I can't make any sense of.

```
(src|href)="\w+|(\w+/)+
```

The way I read this regular expression:

1. Match exactly "src" or "href"
2. Followed by ="
3. Followed by match 1 or more word characters ([a-zA-Z0-9_]) or one or more of (one or more word characters followed by /)

This is meant to match something like 'src="Folder', 'src="folder/', 'href="Folder/SubFolder/', etc.

Input:

> <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>   <head>

Using this regular expression, with this input, there is one match.

> org/1999/

Can anyone possibly explain this? Src or href aren't referenced in the entire string, how can there be any match at all?

Comment: btw, I absolutely love the line "I have developed a regular expression that I can't make any sense of". Classic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening here is the | is seperating the regex into two completely seperate conditions.  That is select either: `(src|href)="\w+` OR `(\w+/)+` of which second bit is being matched:

`org/1999/`

In your case you'd probably need to put the last part in parentheses to make it clear what exactly the alternation `|` refers to:

```
(src|href)="(\w+|(\w+/)+)
```

Btw I used Expresso to help work this out.

Comment: @Joey - Thanks for that I was literally just typing that in :-)

Comment: Ah, wasn't exactly sure, so I just went ahead :P and you were the only one who explained the actual cause instead of just giving a pointer to a tool.

Comment: @Joey - Thanks - I believe you are spot on with the extra parentheses

Comment: This will still not do what you want. Try it with `href="http/www/1999/`: http://refiddle.com/1bi The problem is that `(\w+|(\w+/)+)` will always match `\w+` and stop, even if it could also have matched `(\w+/)+`. Try `(src|href)="\w+((/\w+)*/)?` instead.